# Yesterday,LastWeek,LastMonth Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get Yesterday,Last7Days,LastMonth in single query using a startdate and enddate fields in sql server.

```
Field1      Yesterday       Last7Days       LastMonth
------      ---------       ---------       ----------
row1        count(Records)  count(Records)  count(Records)
row2        count(Records)  count(Records)  count(Records)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select field1,
       sum(case when datecol >= dateadd(day, -2, cast(getdate() as date)) and
                     datecol < cast(getdate() as date)) 
                then 1 else 0
           end) as yesterday,
       sum(case when datecol >= dateadd(day, -8, cast(getdate() as date)) and
                     datecol < cast(getdate() as date)) 
                then 1 else 0
           end) as lastweek,
       sum(case when datecol >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) and
                     datecol < cast(getdate() as date)) 
                then 1 else 0
           end) as lastmonth                     
from t
group by field1;
```